# MatLab load file from relative path

Tags: matlab

I have file `my_file.m` in the directory `C:\...\mydir\`, does not matter which. I have data I wish to load `C:\...\mydir\anotherdir\` which contains my files I wish to load. The following does not seem to work.

```
files = dir('anotherdir\*.mat');
```

I want to load files which are relative to the `my_file.m` which is requesting them.

Answer: To load it further use the following:

```
current_dir = pwd;
files = dir([current_dir '\anotherdir\*.mat']);
dname=[current_dir '\anotherdir\'];

for i=1:length(files)
    fname=fullfile(dname,files(i).name);
    A = load(fname);
end
```

Comment: Could you switch into the folder with `cd('anotherdir')` and then use `files = dir('*.mat');`?

Comment: Cannot CD to anotherdir (Name is nonexistent or not a directory).

Comment: That means that `anotherdir` is not where you think it is, or you are not in the directory directly above it when issuing the `cd` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
current_dir = pwd;
files = dir([current_dir '\anotherdir\*.mat']);
```

Or simply use `cd` as suggested in the comments

Comment: As an aside to the OP, many linux-style commands like `pwd`, `cd`, and `ls` also work in MATLAB. You might be interested in checking them out if you need to manage files and folders in different directory locations. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/file-operations.html